# Reversing the scroll direction of a div with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, scroll

I'm trying to reverse the direction of a scroll gesture for one div in my app. So when you scroll up, the content scrolls down and vice versa.

I haven't seen anything eloquent for ReactJS. I saw this nifty little program for [Angular](https://jsfiddle.net/zanon/sxh9agvm/), but React cannot `preventDefault` for onWheel, so it freezes the scrolling.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Comment: Have you looked at the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) and [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event) `scroll` events?